# Infinite product formula for $\sum_{n \geq 0} p_e(n)\cdot x^n$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, infinite-product, integer-partitions

If $n$ is an integer and $p_e(n)$ is the number of partitions for $n$ such that all parts are even, what would be an infinite product formula for $\sum_{n \geq 0} p_e(n)\cdot x^n$

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? This sounds like a homework problem -- is this reminiscent of any theorems you've seen lately in class? We can help you better when we know exactly where you're struggling ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $x^2$ in the product formula for all partitions.